# Powershell - copy matching strings to a new file using "|" as the separator

Tags: string, powershell, text, copy, copy-paste

I have been trying to write a script which reads through a given file and copies anything in front of "value1: " and "value2" to a new text file. The format bellow if a very similar example.

Input file:

> 20/01/2016 00:00:18    Hsjdjskjlsadnfjk 
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:18    Value1: /test/OLD/myfiles/
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:18    Value2: /test2/NEW/currentfiles/
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:19    kjshfjksfdkls
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:19    Hdjdjndlkasjdflk
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:19    Value1: /match/2015/pages/
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:20    Value2: /replace/2016/pages/
>   
> 20/01/2016 00:00:20    Jdjddn klsndfk

Expected output:

```
/test/OLD/myfiles/|/test2/NEW/currentfiles/|
/match/2015/pages/|/replace/2016/page/|
```

(Pipe as the separator)

Comment: Thanks for tidying up here Liven Keersmaekers

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me. However, it splits on the ':' and space characters, if the string isn't formatted exactly as your example it will not work as expected.

```
$string = "Hsjdjs Value1: /test/ Value2: /test2/ hsuan$&.&:&: Hdjdjnd Value1: /match/ Value2: /replace/ Jdjddn"
$results = $string.Split(": ") | ? {$_  -match "^\/*\/"}
$results -join "|"
```

Output: /test/|/test2/|/match/|/replace/

Edit: Updated for additional requirements. This is about as far as I can take you with this one. Hopefully it works for all the strings you try and parse.

```
[string[]]$lines = @()

$string = "Hsjdjs Value1: /test/ Value2: /test2/ hsuan$&.&:&: Hdjdjnd Value1: /match/ Value2: /replace/ Jdjddn"
$results = ($string -split "Value")

$value1 = $results | ? {$_.StartsWith("1")}
$value2 = $results | ? {$_.StartsWith("2")}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $value1.Count; $i++)
{
    $formattedV1 = ($value1[$i].Trim("1: ") -split "\/*\/")[1]
    $formattedV2 = ($value2[$i].Trim("2: ") -split "\/*\/")[1]

    $lines += [string]::Format("/{0}/|/{1}/|",$formattedV1,$formattedV2)
}

$lines
```

Output is a string array with each index holding a new line.
eg.

```
[0]:/test/|/test2/|
[1]:/match/|/replace/|
```

Comment: Thank you for helping this is actually producing results very close to what i need. If i can get the results from every occurrence of Value1 and Value2 on one line and end each line with Pipe (eg Line 1: "/test/|/test2/|" Line2: "/match/|/replace/|")  it would do just what I need :)

This is the slight modifications i have made so far:

$Input = 'Inputfile.txt'

Comment: I had another play with it and managed to produce the output you're after, see how it goes for you. I'll leave any tinkering from this point onwards up to you.

Comment: Appreciate your help DANGLES